# Accessing parameterised swift method in ObjC class

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

Swift Class:

```
@objc public class XyzClass: NSObject {

    var newlyVar = String()
    func abcd (abc:String?, name:Int) {

    }
    func mymethod(userId:Int32?,startIndex:Int32?, lastIndex:Int32?, m_bankId:Int32?, m_DownPayment:Int32?,m_maxTenure:Int32?, m_salary:Int32?) {

    } 

    func sampleMethod (userId:Int32,startIndex:Int32, lastIndex:Int32, m_bankId:Int32, m_DownPayment:Int32, m_maxTenure:Int32, m_salary:Int32, m_selfemployed:Int32, m_UAENational:Int32, complitionHandler: ( _ success:Bool, _ loans:[Loan]) -> Void){
            complitionHandler(true,[])
    }
}
```

In ObjC class, I'm accessing as:

```
LoanParser *lp = [[LoanParser alloc]init];
[lp abcdWithAbc:@"" name:32];
```

Method `abcd` and variable `newlyVar` is accessible but the `mymethod` and `sampleMethod` isn't.

Anything I'm missing here?

**Concern I feel is: `Loan` class conforms to `Mappable` protocol**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Int32?` cannot be represented in Objective-C. Try changing it to `Int32`.

The String can be represented as optional because it converts to an NSString object which can be nil, so the bridging has a way to represent no value.

Comment: makes sense. ty buddy

Comment: updated question, added a method with completionhandler. please have a look

Comment: I have no issues accessing your `sampleMethod` from ObjC. You've spelled `completion` wrong though.

Comment: it was a `Loan` class parameter of completionhandler, confirming mappable protocol.